# In android, why getCurrentInputEditorInfo() = null?

Tags: android

When clicking a flowWindow button, the application starts a Service extends `InputMethodService` as follow:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int a)
{
super.onStart(intent , a);
EditorInfo ed=getCurrentInputEditorInfo();
}
```

The question is, no matter what the current activity(from other application) is, the "ed" equals "null", of course the following codes such as `"Log.d("tag",ed.hintText+"")"` makes an error.
Is the grammar incorrect, or the application lacks some permission?

Answer (score 1):

Because the EditorInfo doesn't exist until you're connected to a text editor.  This doesn't happen in onStart, it happens in onStartInput.  Where its also passed as a parameter, making this function a bit unnecessary.

Comment: But I don't rewrite an InputMethod. I just want that when there's an editor in the current activity, I can fill some messages to it automatically. Therefore, my first task is to find the EditorInfo. How could i do that?

Comment: If you aren't writing an InputMethod, then you have no need to know the editor info.  I think you're confused.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am writing an application, which can fill the validate form automatically. For example, with the application running in background, when I launch Youtube, it can detect the editorInfo and fill the id and password with datas fetching from database automatically.

Comment: The editorInfo is a concept only to an input method.  It provides very limited information about the generic type of editor that is currently attached to the input method- that the user has tapped inside to focus.  What you want to do would require you to be a part of the browser, a plug-in.  Even if you were able to get an EditorInfo, it normally doesn't give you more info than numeric/text/password and possibly a few flags for caps mode.  It would never say "Yahoo login id" or "Yahoo password".

Comment: Also, only the currently selected input method gets called at all-  ony the user's chosen keyboard.  Its not like Android calls every input method service with this info.  So you won't get called and passed an editor info unless you're the current keyboard.